Clear but not glass
Clear but not glass
Deep but not sea
Things are mixed into it
But touched it may not be.
Think carefully, for it is in plain sight…
Once you have it, you will know you are right.

Clear but not glass

 insight is an acute clear observation

Deep but not sea

 insight is penetrating

Things are mixed into it

 insight can be made from the letters in 'things'

But touched it may not be.

 it's not tangible

Think carefully, for it is in plain sight…

 it is in plain sight...

Once you have it, you will know you are right.

 this insight fits the clues.


I was thinking "thought", but didn't know that I was right, so I thought better and checked the spoilers :)
